# SwiftUI: make buttons the same height, and fill the container?

Tags: swiftui

I have a row of `.bordered` image buttons. And I want all of them to fill the height of the container, by setting `frame(maxHeight: .infinity)`. However, although the buttons themselves are properly sized, the gray background depicting the border is not. See the attached image. Basically, I want the gray background to fill up to the blue borders.

[image: Bordered buttons do not appear to be the same height]

And here's the simplified code I have.

```
HStack {
  Button(action: { }) {
    Image(systemName: "phone.connection.fill").foregroundColor(.green)
  }
  .buttonStyle(.bordered).fixedSize()
  .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
  .border(Color.blue)

  Button(action: {  }) {
    Image(systemName: "phone.down.fill").foregroundColor(.gray)

  }
  .disabled(true)
  .buttonStyle(.bordered).fixedSize()
  .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
  .border(Color.blue)

  ...
  
}
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `View` is close, but the placement of the `frame` and `fixedSize` modifiers have to be changed a bit:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
          Button(action: { }) {
            Image(systemName: "phone.connection.fill")
                  .foregroundColor(.green)
          }
          .buttonStyle(.bordered)
          .border(Color.blue)

          Button(action: {  }) {
            Image(systemName: "phone.down.fill")
                  .foregroundColor(.gray)
                  .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
          }
          .disabled(true)
          .buttonStyle(.bordered)
          .border(Color.blue)
        }
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        .border(Color.green)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Aha, got it. Thanks. The image itself needs to have an `infinity` height to fill it its parent, the button!